# Hide map borders and labels in android MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, mapfragment

I have a MapFragment object that I would like to modify, so that all the labels: county,street and such wont be visible. also the borders of the counties wont be visible...
so that I'll get only the topography.

how could I do that?

Comment: Try build custom map.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html), you can style your maps to look whatever you want it to look like, and apply the style to the [Static Maps](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=35.32773,139.491348&zoom=9&format=png&sensor=false&size=640x480&maptype=roadmap&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:transit%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:road%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:administrative%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:water%7Celement:labels%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:landscape%7Celement:labels%7Cvisibility:off), or [apply the style to your map](http://jsfiddle.net/1dbmupfj/2/).

```
[
  {
    "featureType": "poi",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "road",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
      { "visibility": "off" }
    ]
  },{
  }
]
```

Comment: not what I needed... I meant for android not for javascript

Comment: this style can apply to both android and js, also please refer to [apply the style to your map](http://jsfiddle.net/1dbmupfj/2/)

Comment: kaho the style link you provided is for Google Maps in Javascript. @Noyloy and I and referring to Native Android App displaying Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

I could get a close enough result just by specifying map type to be satellite.

here googleMap object is the map from the MapFragment:
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);